# Relationship laravel with unique count

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a problem in creating a query that contains the count of elements in another table by grouping the elements by a column.

I try to explain the problem with this example:

**Table post**

| id | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first |
| 2 | second |

**Table views**

| id | post_id | view_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |

**Post model**

```
class Post extends Model{

  protected $table = 'post';

  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  protected $fillable = [
    'title'
  ];

  public function related_views(){

    return $this->hasMany(Views::class, 'post_id', 'id');

  }

}
```

**Views model**

```
class Views extends Model{

  protected $table = 'views';

  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  protected $fillable = [
    'post_id',
    'view_id'
  ];

}
```

**Query**

```
$query = Post::with([
                'related_views' => function ($query) {
                    return $query->groupBy('view_id');
                }
            ])
            ->withCount('related_views')
            ->get();
```

The query is executed correctly. In the multidimensional array that is returned there are, in addition to the columns in the main table, these 2 values: related_views and related_views_count.

The related_views_count variable counts all the elements while the related_views variable shows only the elements by grouping.

Is it possible to get the count of the elements in the related_views variable instead of getting the array of elements?

I hope I have stated my problem correctly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear what output you're getting, and what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. @miken32 Today a user replied to my question giving me a solution consistent with what I asked. Unfortunately it did not work but as I kept trying I found the solution which I posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this query I solved the problem!

```
Post::query()
  ->withCount('related_views', function($query) {
          $query->select(DB::raw('count(distinct(view_id))'));
  })
->get();
```